# Shopify Backup Changes Routed to Hosted Domain GoDaddy

Tags: shopify, godaddy-api

I am currently making changes in a live shop. So I have duplicated my live theme and am making changes in my duplicate.

Still all my changes are visible in my live website. Somehow, all my themes in my shop are routed to my hosted domain at GoDaddy.

Does anyone have an idea how I can prevent this from happening and can only route my live theme to GoDaddy?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the duplicate theme `dev` and the live one `live`. They are all hosted on the same domain from GoDaddy

This should be the way to modify `dev` vs `live` environment, by using `theme kit` and use `git` to track files

[3 Simple Steps for Setting Up a Local Shopify Theme Development Environment](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/95401862-3-simple-steps-for-setting-up-a-local-shopify-theme-development-environment)

[Live Reloading Shopify Themes: Sass Compilation with Theme Kit and Prepros](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/live-reload-shopify-sass)

Base on the information you gave, I will check the following

-check that you are not previewing the `dev` theme.

-check that when you are editing the correct theme.

-make sure to only edit files offline. This will save you so much trouble.

Comment: Hello Charles, thank you for your reply! I have themekit set up and have configured themekit config.yml file for my DEV theme. Changes in from themekit in my DEV theme immediately go live on my Hosted domain, so my customers can see it.. Can I somehow configure GoDaddy Hosting to only host my PROD theme?

Comment: Apparently for the computer on which there is testing of a non-published theme, the hosted is seen as the theme in Preview. So the fact that I can see changes on a non-published theme on my real domain is limited to my computer. Which eliminates the problem. So on other screens you cannot see these non-published changes. So everything ok.. :-) Thanks